# pathlib.Path.exists returns False for broken symlink

Tags: python, linux, symlink

Consider this setup in a command line:

```
touch test.txt
ln -s test.txt test.lnk
rm test.txt
```

So we have a broken symlink that points to deleted file. Now in Python:

```py
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('test.lnk')
p.is_symlink()  # True
p.exists()  # False
```

Python tells me that "`test.lnk` is a symlink, but it doesn't exist..." 
Because of that I am not able to check correctly if there is something named `test.lnk` in a directory:

```py
if not p.exists():
    p.symlink_to('another_file')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1384, in symlink_to
#     self._accessor.symlink(target, self, target_is_directory)
#   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 446, in symlink
#     return os.symlink(a, b)
# FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'another_file' -> 'test.lnk'
```

How do I work around that? What is the correct way to check if a broken symlink exists in Python?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do in the case of broken symlink? Unhandled exception (so you don't overwrite the broken symlink) or just overwrite the link?  `p.is_symlink()  # True` is _already_ telling you that there is a symlink named `test.lnk` in the directory (otherwise this would either return `False` or cause a `FileNotFoundError`)

Comment: @wim it is a general question, I want to execute arbitrary code in case if symlink exists and other code if not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `exists()` is doing exactly what the document says it does when a symlink points to a non-existent file.

> Note If the path points to a symlink, exists() returns whether the
> symlink points to an existing file or directory.

Pretty much every function returns `false` when given a broken symlink. In some sense the file doesn't actually exist.

Would `file.is_symlink() or file.exists()` do what you want it to do?

Comment: `file.is_symlink() or file.exists()` doesn't look like a right way. In extrapolation it will be `file.exists() or file.is_symlink() or something_else() or something_else_2()` and so on. I hope that there is a general way to tell if there is anything (file, directory, symlink, broken symlink) in a directory that has given name (test.lnk in my example).

Comment: @sanyassh:  I sort of agree with you and was hesitant to write what I wrote.  But looking through the documentation, symlink appeared to be the only anomaly, and has been the only anomaly for a while.

Answer (score 0):

To check if *anything* is present, including a broken symlink, it would be better to use the [`lstat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.lstat) method:

```
try:
    file.lstat()
except FileNotFoundError:
    # file doesn't exist, for real this time!
    ...
```

As a bonus, this also avoids a bunch of [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race conditions that [`exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists)-based approaches may suffer from.

Comment: What type is "file" in your solution?

Comment: @JasonHarrison It's a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) instance, and [`Path.lstat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.lstat) is a method.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.8, the standard `os.path` library embed the [lexists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.lexists) function that does exactly what you search for